# I'm using a min-heap here, but i'm doing it wrong. I'm trying to print out some sheep in breadth order while also being sorted lightest to heaviest

Tags: java, heap, min-heap

My heap is suppposed to print out in breadth order and sort the sheep from lightest to heaviest (min-heap). My test file should add 15 sheep and remove at least 5.  I havent attempted the remove part yet because i'm getting an array index out of bounds error.  Any help is appreciated.

Here are my classes:

```
public class Sheep {

    private double weight;
    private String name;

    public Sheep()
    {
        weight = 0.0;
        name = "null";
    }

    public Sheep(double aWeight, String aName)
    {
        this.weight = aWeight;
        this.name = aName;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    //may not be necessary...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Sheep [weight=" + weight + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }

    //this may not be necessary...
    public int compareTo(Sheep sheep)
    {
        if (this.weight>sheep.weight)
            return 1;
        else if(this.weight<sheep.weight)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}

//****************************************


public class SheepHeapMain {

    private Sheep[]heap;
    private static int size;
    private static final int FIRST=1; //possibly needed, how do you do this


    public SheepHeapMain()
    {
        heap = (Sheep[])(new Comparable[100]);
        size = 0;
    }
    public SheepHeapMain(int aSize)
    {
        heap = new Sheep[aSize];
    }

    public void addSheep(Sheep val)
    {
        if(size >= heap.length)
        {
            System.out.println("Max size of heap has been reached");
            return;
        }
        heap[size] = val;
        climbUp();
        size++;
    }

    public void climbUp()
    {
        int index = this.size;
        while(index>0 &&//It has a parent
                heap[index/2].compareTo(heap[index])<0)//And the value of the child is greater than the parent
        {
            //SWAP
            Sheep temp = heap[index/2];
            heap[index/2] = heap[index];
            heap[index] = temp;
            index = index/2;
        }
    }

    public Sheep peek()
    {
        if(heap == null)
            return null;
        return heap[0];
    }

    public Sheep removeSheep()
    {
        Sheep returnVal = peek();
         heap[0] = heap[size-1]; //index Out of bonunds error
         heap[size-1] = null;
         size--;

         climbDown();
        return returnVal;
    }

    public void climbDown()
    {
        int index = 0;
        while(index*2+1 < size)//While there is a left child
        {
            //Find smallest child
            int bigIndex = index*2+1;
            if(index*2+2 < size &&
                    heap[index*2+1].compareTo(heap[index*2+2])>0) //Right was bigger than left so change it
            {
                bigIndex = index*2+2;
            }

            if(heap[index].compareTo(heap[bigIndex])<0)//If current index is greater than smaller index
            {
                //SWAP
                Sheep temp = heap[index];
                heap[index] = heap[bigIndex];
                heap[bigIndex] = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                break;//We're done!
            }
            index = bigIndex;//Update the index to continue
        }
    }

    public void sheepRollCall()
    {
        for(Sheep thing : heap)
        {
            if(thing == null)
                break;
            System.out.println(thing.toString());
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public static void sheepHeapSort(SheepHeapMain heap)
    {
        SheepHeapMain tempheap = heap;
        for(int i=size;i>0;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(tempheap.removeSheep()+" ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

//****************************************************************


public class SheepHeapTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int heapSize = 15;
        SheepHeapMain heap = new SheepHeapMain(heapSize);

        heap.addSheep(new Sheep(55,"Jimmy"));
        heap.addSheep(new Sheep(43,"Ricky"));
        heap.addSheep(new Sheep(77,"Larry"));
        heap.addSheep(new Sheep(12,"Suzie Q"));
        heap.addSheep(new Sheep(91,"Curly"));
        heap.addSheep(new Sheep(85,"Bubba"));
        heap.addSheep(new Sheep(189,"MEGA SHEEP"));
        heap.addSheep(new Sheep(46,"Bo Peep"));
        heap.addSheep(new Sheep(27,"Queenie"));
        heap.addSheep(new Sheep(19,"Fluffy"));

        System.out.println("current thing is");
        heap.sheepRollCall();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Sorted Sheepies :)");
        SheepHeapMain.sheepHeapSort(heap);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because you are trying to reference index of -1 in your `heap` array.

I added a line to print `size` and `heap.length`:

```
public Sheep removeSheep()
    {
        System.out.println("removeSheep size: " + size + " array size: " + heap.length);
        Sheep returnVal = peek();
         heap[0] = heap[size-1]; //index Out of bonunds error
         heap[size-1] = null;
         size--;

         climbDown();
        return returnVal;
    }
```

And here is the output:

```
Sorted Sheepies :)
removeSheep size: 10 array size: 15
Sheep [weight=189.0, name=MEGA SHEEP] 

removeSheep size: 9 array size: 15
Sheep [weight=77.0, name=Larry] 

removeSheep size: 8 array size: 15
Sheep [weight=27.0, name=Queenie] 

removeSheep size: 7 array size: 15
Sheep [weight=46.0, name=Bo Peep] 

removeSheep size: 6 array size: 15
Sheep [weight=19.0, name=Fluffy] 

removeSheep size: 5 array size: 15
Sheep [weight=55.0, name=Jimmy] 

removeSheep size: 4 array size: 15
Sheep [weight=43.0, name=Ricky] 

removeSheep size: 3 array size: 15
Sheep [weight=85.0, name=Bubba] 

removeSheep size: 2 array size: 15
Sheep [weight=91.0, name=Curly] 

removeSheep size: 1 array size: 15
Sheep [weight=12.0, name=Suzie Q] 

removeSheep size: 0 array size: 15
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at SheepHeapMain.removeSheep(SheepHeapMain.java:55)
    at SheepHeapMain.sheepHeapSort(SheepHeapMain.java:107)
    at SheepHeapTester.main(SheepHeapTester.java:24)
```

As for fixing your code, here is a standard heap-sort algorithm that sorts in descending order using a min-heap that you can use as a reference:

```
public class HeapSort {

  private static int getLeft(int index) {
      return index * 2 + 1;
  }
  private static int getRight(int index) {
      return index * 2 + 2;
  }
  private static void exchange (int[] arr, int first, int second) {

      int temp = arr[first];
      arr[first] = arr[second];
      arr[second] = temp;
  }
  private static void minHeapify (int[] arr, int size, int index) {

      int left = getLeft(index);
      int right = getRight(index);
      int minIndex = index;

      if (left < size && arr[left] < arr[minIndex]) 
        minIndex = left;

      if (right < size && arr[right] < arr[minIndex]) 
        minIndex = right;

      if (index != minIndex) {

          exchange(arr, index, minIndex);

          minHeapify (arr, size, minIndex);
      }

  }
  private static void buildMinHeap (int[] arr) {
      int size = arr.length;
      for (int i = ((size-1) / 2); i >= 0; i --) {
          // Do max-heapify on the i.
          minHeapify (arr, size, i);
      }
  }
  public static void heapSort(int[] arr) {
      int size = arr.length;

      buildMinHeap(arr);

      for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

          exchange (arr, 0, i);

          minHeapify (arr, i, 0);

          showArray(arr);

      }
  }

  public static void showArray (int[] arr) {
      int size = arr.length;
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
          System.out.print(String.format("%-4d", arr[i]));
      System.out.println();
  }


  public static void main (String[] args) {

      int[] arr = {53, 42, 86, 11, 27, -5, 89, 0};

      heapSort(arr);

      showArray(arr);
  }
}
```